# vueX with vuei18n. this.dispatch is not able to access vuei18n

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I am relatively new to Vue and I've been reading the documentation and forums for quite a while for a solution to this one but haven't found it yet. 
I am using the Vue Webpack template: [here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)

I'm trying to create an app where I have an API endpoint to get the currency and country for the user as well as the user language from the browser.

I am using this.$store.dispatch('setlanguage') on initialisation of the Vue Component to set the state of the language, and save it to a cookie. The problem here though is that I am unable to alter the vuei18n as my app says it does not exist. The reason I am using vuei18n instead of vueXi18n is because the latter does not have the numberFormat options and this is needed in order to set correctly the currency symbols.
So to get things started:

Project structure:

```
main.js
App.Vue
 store
   getters.js
   index.js
   mutation-types.js
   mutations.js
 router
   index.js
 lang
   locales
     en.js
     fr.js
     de.js
   lang.js
 components
   LocaleSwitcher.vue
 pages
   Footer.vue
   Home.vue
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import App from './App.vue'
import i18n from './lang/lang'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.config.language = Cookies.get('lang')
Vue.config.country = Cookies.get('country')
Vue.config.currency = Cookies.get('cur')

export const localeStrings = {
  en: 'English',
  de: 'Deutsch',
  fr: 'Français',
  it: 'Italiano',
  nl: 'Nederlands',
  sv: 'Svenska',
  es: 'Español',
  ja: '日本語'
}

export const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',      
  router,
  store,
  i18n: i18n,
  render: h => h(App),
  created () {       
    this.$store.dispatch('setLang', Vue.config.language)
    this.$store.dispatch('setCountry', Vue.config.country)        
  }     
})
```

lang.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

let i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages: {},
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  numberFormats: {}
})

export default {i18n}
```

App.vue

```
template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="main-content">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'myapp',
  components: {    
    'app-footer': Footer
  },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      language: ''
    }
  }
}
<style>
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
</style>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello Home! {{msg}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Home msg'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Footer.vue

```
<template>
  <footer>
    <p>{{copyright}}</p>
    <local-switcher></local-switcher>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
import LocaleSwitcher from '../components/LocaleSwitcher.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Footer',
  components: {
    'local-switcher': LocaleSwitcher
  },
  data () {
    return {          
      copyright: 'Copyright 2018 Francesco'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
footer{
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

LocaleSwitcher.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="locale-switcher">
    <select v-model="activeLocale" @change="changeLang">
      <option v-for="(lang, id) in locales" :key="id" v-bind:value="id">{{lang}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {localeStrings} from '../main'

export default {
  name: 'locale-switcher',
  data: function () {
    return {
      activeLocale: this.$store.getters.getLanguage,
      locales: localeStrings
    }
  }, 
  methods: {   
    changeLang () {
      this.setLang(this.activeLocale)
    },
    setLang (lang) {
      this.$store.dispatch('setLang', lang)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import p404 from '../pages/error/404.vue'
import Home from '../pages/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: '404',
    component: p404
  }  
]

let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

// I still have to figure out how to use this to set www.mypage.com/mylanguage/home
// use beforeEach route guard to set the language
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // use the language from the routing param or default language
  let language = to.params.lang
  console.log(language)
  console.log('router end')
  if (!language) {
    language = 'en'
  }
  // set the current language for vuex-i18n. note that translation data
  // for the language might need to be loaded first
  // Vue.i18n.set(language)
  next()
})

export default router
```

store/getters.js

```
export const getters = {
  getLanguage: state => {
    return state.language
  },
  getCountry: state => {
    return state.country
  },
  getCurrency: state => {
    return state.currency
  }
}
```

store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { state, mutations, actions } from './mutations'
import { getters } from './getters'

Vue.use(Vuex)

// const mapState = Vuex.mapState
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
})

export default store
```

store/mutation-types.js

```
export const SET_LANG = 'SET_LANG'
export const SET_COUNTRY = 'SET_COUNTRY'
export const SET_CURRENCY = 'SET_CURRENCY'
```

store/mutations.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import * as types from './mutation-types'
import {app, supportedLocale, supportedCurrencies} from '../main'
import CountryCurrency from '../data/country_currency.json'
import locale2 from 'locale2'

export const state = {
  language: Cookies.get(settings.languageCookie),
  country: Cookies.get(settings.countryCookie),
  currency: Cookies.get(settings.currencyCookie),
  loading: false
}

export const mutations = {
  [types.SET_LANG] (state, payload) {    
    Cookies.set('lang', payload)
    state.language = payload
  },
  [types.SET_COUNTRY] (state, payload) {
    Cookies.set('country', payload)
    state.country = payload
  },
  [types.SET_CURRENCY] (state, payload) {
    Cookies.set('currency', payload)
    state.currency = payload
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async setLang ({commit}, language) {
    console.log(app)
    console.log(Vue)
    var vueMessages = app.$i18n.messages

  var userLocale = 'en'
  var browserLocale = locale2.split('-', 1)[0]
  // testing browser language
  if (locale === undefined) {
    // get browser language
    userLocale = browserLocale
  } else if (browserLocale !== locale) {
    console.log('browser language changed')
    userLocale = browserLocale
  } else {
    userLocale = locale
  }
  // check for supported languages
  if (!supportedLocale.includes(userLocale)) {
    userLocale = 'en'
  }
    if (language in vueMessages) {
      console.log('already in messages')
      commit(types.SET_LANG, language)
    } else if (!supportedLocale.includes(language)) {
      console.log('not supported so commiting default en')
      commit(types.SET_LANG, 'en')
    } else {
      try {
        // you can use fetch or import which ever you want.
        // Just make sure your webpack support import syntax
        // const res = await axios.get(`./src/lang/${payload}.json`)
        const res = await import(`../lang/locales/${language}.json`)
        app.$i18n.locale = language
        app.$i18n.setLocaleMessage(language, res)
        var addNumberFormats = {
          currency: {
            style: 'currency', currencyDisplay: 'symbol', currency: `${app.$i18n.currency}`
          }
        }
        app.$i18n.mergeNumberFormat(language, addNumberFormats)
        Cookies.set('lang', language)
        commit(types.SET_LANG, language)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
  },
setCountry ({commit}, countryCode) {
    var userCountry = 'NA'
    if (countryCode === undefined || countryCode === 'NA') {
      Vue.http.get('https://www.myapi.com/api/v2/geo/country-code', {
        timeout: 100
      }).then(response => {
        state.country = response.data.code
        Cookies.set('country', response.data.code)
      }, response => {
        // error callback
        state.country = userCountry
        Cookies.set('country', userCountry)
      })
    } else {
      console.log(countryCode)          
      state.country = countryCode
      Cookies.set('country', countryCode)
    }
  },
  setCurrency ({commit}, countryCode) {
    var userCurrency = 'USD'
    console.log('user country ' + countryCode)
    console.log('user currency ' + CountryCurrency[countryCode])
    console.log('currency supported: ' + supportedCurrencies.includes(CountryCurrency[countryCode]))

    if (CountryCurrency[countryCode] && supportedCurrencies.includes(CountryCurrency[countryCode])) {
      userCurrency = CountryCurrency[countryCode]
    }

    Cookies.set('currency', userCurrency)
    app.$i18n.currency = userCurrency

    try {
      var addNumberFormats = {
        currency: {
          style: 'currency', currencyDisplay: 'symbol', currency: `${app.$i18n.currency}`
        }
      }
      if (!app.$i18n.numberFormats[app.$i18n.locale]) {
        console.log('merge currency')
        app.$i18n.setNumberFormat(app.$i18n.locale, addNumberFormats)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that once loaded, I cannot access the app vue i18n. Am I accessing it incorrectly or is there another way to add language and currency settings to this? I hope I have provided enough info Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could this answer be relevant in your case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45460729/2964531

If you need to access or mutate properties of i18n, you can import it directly from store/mutations.js

Comment: Yes of course I tried something like that, the thing is I need to access the app Vue so that I can add to and modify the Vue i18n messages and number formats asynchronously I would add the languages accordingly instead of loading every language. Thing is when using dispatch, I cannot read the properties of app, whilst when the page loads, these are available. So basically, printing the app properties in the mutations.js will result in outputting nothing.